# Empty clipboard using vba

Tags: r, excel, vba

I am trying to read data from excel, send it to R for analysis and paste results in R. A warning message must be displayed whenever there is an error in connection to R and clipboard needs to be emptied before that.

Problem in emptying clipboard. 
I tried

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You can replace clipboard content with something else, e.g. `ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Copy`